# Может ли завейтится все приложения если я использую один монитор?

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

У меня есть два потока. 
В одном потоке, который запустился сразу имеется такой код

```
public void run(){ MONITOR.wait(); ...}
```

Во втором потоке, который стартует через 10 секунд после первого, такой код:

```
public void run(){ MONITOR.notify(); MONITOR.wait();...}
```

Может ли получиться, что оба потока  будут в **wait**?
Такой вопрос мне задали на собеседовании, я сказал, что не может, мне сказали вы ошиблись подумайте. Кто был прав? Джава док на моей стороне, но все же хотелось уточнить.
Можете привести пример ситуации, когда оба потока будут в wait одновременно, из-за каких-то причин?
Первое что приходит в голову на второй вопрос - это поменять wait и notify во втором потоке местами.

Comment: @zRrr  Но я слабо представляю себе такую ситуацию, даже если я жестко привяжу поток к ядру, укажу ему минимальный приоритет и загружу это ядро, высоко приоритетными потоками, разве тогда есть вероятность такого исхода? 
Можно ли в джавадоке о таком почитать?

Comment: Не думаю что в JavaDoc про это будет написано. Это общее понятие многопоточности, что потоки выполняются параллельно без предписанного порядка во времени. Т.е. вы не можете гарантировать 100% в вашем примере, что первый wait отработает раньше notify. На практике проблем не будет, а теоретически - нельзя быть на 100% уверенным. P.S. в коде еще нужно добавить synchronized и try/catch

Comment: @zRrr было бы здорово, если бы ты сформулировал и оставил бы ответ на этот вопрос

Comment: @zRrr все таки распишите, пожалуйста, по шагам - как такое может быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый, как мне кажется, простой вариант ответа следующий. 
Если система сильно нагружена, то даже если первый поток запущен на 10 секунд раньше, это не значит что он первым захватит монитор и войдет synchronized блок (может до этого выполняются более приоритетные задачи на компьютере). Соответственно, возможна ситуация когда первым захватит монитор второй поток. Следовательно, второй поток может выполнить MONITOR.notify(); тогда, когда на первом потоке еще не вызвали MONITOR.wait();
Вследствие этого, оба потока уходят в wait.